# iOS Production crash - EXC_BAD_ACCESS / KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS / CFDictionaryGetValue + 80

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, performance, firebase-performance

**Hey There,
My app was working fine until the last release i found that it crashes on App Store environment without any clear reason,**

then i received a report regarding the crash and this is the logs:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0002603700000000

Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [592]
Triggered by Thread:  6

Thread 6 name:
Thread 6 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019f610fbc CFDictionaryGetValue + 80 (CFInternal.h:845)
1   Foundation                      0x000000019fa82114 _NSSetLongLongValueAndNotify + 88 (NSKeyValueObserverNotifying.m:64)
2   Foundation                      0x000000019fa82114 _NSSetLongLongValueAndNotify + 88 (NSKeyValueObserverNotifying.m:64)
3   CFNetwork                       0x00000001a2ac4e00 __51-[NSURLSession delegate_task:didCompleteWithError:]_block_invoke.194 + 60 (Session.mm:676)
4   Foundation                      0x000000019fa9e3f0 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16 (NSOperation.m:1541)
5   Foundation                      0x000000019f9a9710 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 84 (NSOperation.m:1560)
6   Foundation                      0x000000019faa064c __NSOPERATION_IS_INVOKING_MAIN__ + 20 (NSOperation.m:2184)
7   Foundation                      0x000000019f9a9414 -[NSOperation start] + 740 (NSOperation.m:2201)
8   Foundation                      0x000000019faa1044 __NSOPERATIONQUEUE_IS_STARTING_AN_OPERATION__ + 20 (NSOperation.m:2215)
9   Foundation                      0x000000019faa0b10 __NSOQSchedule_f + 180 (NSOperation.m:2226)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019f341c8c _dispatch_block_async_invoke2 + 104 (queue.c:525)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019f38f524 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:495)
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019f337e98 _dispatch_continuation_pop$VARIANT$mp + 412 (inline_internal.h:2484)
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019f3375ec _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 656 (queue.c:803)
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019f344438 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 376 (inline_internal.h:2525)
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019f344bf8 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 124 (queue.c:6628)
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019f3e0b38 _pthread_wqthread + 212 (pthread.c:2368)
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019f3e3740 start_wqthread + 8
```

And Unfortunately i didn't got it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FINALY I FOUND THE SOLUTION**

The issue was about Firebase/Performance pod,

i think the best workaround for now is to remove it or to downgrade it to 6.34

Reference: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/6734